# How do I fill the "Transaction Details" key/value table inside the Transaction screen of Magento Admin?

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I've created a custom payment gateway but now I need to handle post payment notifications (just like IPN) to append additional information for a given transaction.

I've tried a lot of different combinations including:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load('#id')
    ->getPayment()
        ->getTransaction('#id')
            ->setAdditionalInformation('foo', 'bar')
                ->save();
```

Which doesn't produce any error (I'm able to retrieve order/payment/transaction)
But save action seems to be inoperant. I also tried to save through the payment object without luck.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the version you are using, but at least on EE 1.12.x this seems to be the right way to do it, and the below answer doesn't work. In fact due to `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS` used in adminhtml block I could not get this information to show in the admin, so had to override with a version with calls the getter without any params.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out by myself :P

```
$payment->getTransaction($id)
    ->setAdditionalInformation(
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS,
        $data
    )->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you´re trying to include information on the "authorize" stage of paymnet, here´s an useful snippet (please change variables to your own data!):

```
public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount) {
    .....
   $_data = array( 'Tranx' => $_transax, 'Auth' => $_autho ...);
   $payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(
                Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS,
                $_data);
   $payment->setTransactionId($_authid)->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
   return $this
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$transactin_detail = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id)->getPayment()->getTransaction($transId)->save();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($transactin_detail);
```